# Designing "Shirt" Class in Object Oriented Way

Tags: oop, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

I was discussing an exercise design problem with my friend and we came up with different solution. We are learning OOPS concept, so decided to show our solution here to experts and get their opinion.

**Problem:** Design class for Shirts. Shirts have different features like pattern, size, color etc.

**Friend's Solution:**

[image: Shirts Class Diagram]

**My Solution:**

[image: Shirts Class Diagram with lots of Interfaces]

There would be concrete implementations, for example, small, medium, large for Size. Red, Blue, Yellow for Color. Isn't using Interfaces for Pattern, Size, Color is an overkill? Polymorphism should be used to encapsulate behavior, but I am using it in different way.

May some expert please let us know how we should hold different features of Shirt in Object Oriented Way? How to handle new features (e.g., shades) if they come in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your friend's idea is simple and I like to start with simple ideas and improve them when needed. On the other hand your solution provides great flexibility and you took OOP to the maximum by using an interface type for each variable instead of native types.

Regarding the last thing you mentioned on handling new features, well in both designs you have to open the class for modification which is not a great thing as it violates the OCP principle (classes should be open extension, closed  for modification).

I would solve that by letting the `Shirt` class hold properties which are common to all shirts like size, color, price or whatever and store the rest of the features that can vary in a `HashMap` or a `PropertyList`.

This gives great flexibility as when new features come-in you just call a method like `AddFeature(name, value)` that stores the feature in the `HashMap`.

I wanna make one point pretty clear, don't deep dive into design and let it consume your time. Instead start with simple ideas and improve them as you go on. Great design comes from experience and careful analysis of the business domain.

Comment: +1 to start with simple and improve. Beware with the usage of `HashMap`. Eventhough it can be used in logics like properties, but it is ugly to refer with string. Also it is not duplicateable. Moreover, usually I use interface in `entities` only for optional property, not mandatory fields such as color and size (in this case pattern may apply).

Comment: @Fendy It is a bit ugly a bit indeed, but you can hide it behind well named methods. I didn't get the part about using an interface in entities, what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I am misunderstanding with C#-based interfaces. It has property exposed instead of methods. And usually I do anemic domain model instead of rich entity, so I distinguish between service class and entity (model) class.

Comment: @Fendy OK I see, well usually I go down that route *(anemic model)* when I am building a heavily CRUD application. Thanks for your notes.